Issue with Dynamic Block and Attributes in AutoCAD Net
I am encountering while working with Dynamic Blocks and Attributes in AutoCAD.
I have created a Dynamic Block with two visibility states: option1 and option2. option2 is essentially a 180-degree rotated version of option1. Both options have corresponding attributes.
In my C# code, I have successfully set the attributes for both option1 and option2 to be identical. However, I am facing an issue when viewing the block in AutoCAD. Although I change the visibility states between option1 and option2, the properties window in AutoCAD only recognizes and displays the attributes for option1. As a result, option2 does not show as expected.
It seems that despite altering the visibility options in the properties window, AutoCAD only accepts attribute1 as the parameter, leading to option2 not displaying correctly.
I hope to get guidance from you.
public static void InsertVertexInformation(this PipeRunViewModel _PipeRun)
{
    Document acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
    Database acCurDb = acDoc.Database;
    acDoc.LockDocument();

    string runNameOnCad = _PipeRun.DisplayName;
    runNameOnCad = runNameOnCad.Substring(0, runNameOnCad.Length - 3);

    SmartCADRepository repository = new SmartCADRepository();
    List<DBVertex> vertices = repository.GetAllVerTexOfPipeRun(_PipeRun.OID);
    if (vertices == null || vertices.Count == 0) return;
    double bop = 0;
    using (Transaction acTrans = acCurDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == vertices.Count - 1) break;
            Point3d vertex1 = vertices[i].Location;
            Point3d vertex2 = new Point3d(vertices[i + 1].Location.X, vertices[i + 1].Location.Y, 0);

            if (new Point3d(vertex1.X, vertex1.Y, 0).DistanceTo(vertex2) < 500) continue;

            Point3d insertPoint = new Point3d((vertex1.X + vertex2.X) / 2.0, (vertex1.Y + vertex2.Y) / 2.0, 0);
            double od = repository.GetPipeOD(_PipeRun.OID);
            bop = vertices[i].Location.Z - od / 2.0;

            Dictionary<string, string> AttributeTag = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "ELEVATION1", Convert.ToString(vertices[i].Location.Z) },
                { "ELEVATION2", Convert.ToString(vertices[i].Location.Z) },
                { "BOP1", bop.ToString() },
                { "BOP2", bop.ToString() },
                { "ANGLE1", Convert.ToString(vertices[i].Angle) },
                { "ANGLE2", Convert.ToString(vertices[i].Angle) },
                { "LINENAME1", runNameOnCad },
                { "LINENAME2", runNameOnCad }
            };
            BlockReference bkr = acDoc.InsertBlockReference(acTrans, "VERTEXINF", insertPoint, vertex2, default, 0, AttributeTag);
            if (bkr == null) break;
            BlockReferenceExtension.UpdateXDATA(bkr, "VERTEXINF", vertices[i].OIDVertex, _PipeRun.OID);
        }
        acTrans.Commit();
    }
}


expected 
Attribute when change Options
Rotation Text when I change Option1->option2
